# Linear PEI Solution Making

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm making a solution with linear [poly(ethyleneimine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylenimine) $\ce{[CH2CH2NH]_{n}}$.  The bottle indicates that the substance is hygroscopic and must be dealt with under inert gas.  Is this really necessary?  I don't currently have access to such a space - just the PEI and a balance.

Comment: Well, depends if water in your solution makes problem.